# Kodi on a GPIO screen

Tags: gpio, kodi, touchscreen

I recently bought a 3.5 inch TFT touchscreen connected by GPIO to my raspberry.
I finally managed to make it work with Raspbian.
however, when I launch KODI, the image on the TFT freezes and KODI works only through HDMI. 
Does someone know how to get the display of KODI on the TFT screen?

Comment: Can you give us the make and model of touchscreen and explain what you had to do to "make it work with raspbian" please?

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked for me was with `fbcp`, basically a small program that copies the frame buffer from `fb0` to `fb1`; does not render so fast but it works.

Comment: Is there a reason, why `fb1` cannot be used directly?